# After installing angular version 12, another version 13 also installed together. I just need version 12. How to remove version 13?

Tags: angular, npm

```
C:\Users\eaind>npm install -g @angular/cli@12.0.2
```

[image: angular version 12.0.2]

I installed version 12 under `C:\Users\eaind\` , and when I check the ng -v it show cli-only in versions.
After that I change the path to `C:\Windows\System32` and check the version again.

```
C:\Windows\Sytem32>ng -v
```

[image]

It show the angular version `13.3.0`. I open the command prompt with admin mode in both paths.
Why is happening like this and I want only `12.0.2` version. How to solve this problem?

And environment paths are

```
C:\Users\eaind\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\Users\eaind\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

Comment: Did you try `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@13.3.0`?

Comment: Yes, I tried. It says up to date in 0.043s. And when I check again ng version, it still there showing angular cli version 13.3.0.

Comment: But when I type `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` with this, uninstallation works and `ng version` got errors.

Comment: try to find the global node_modules in folder in your system, find the angular cli folder(`@angular`) and remove it. `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues, I tried several installs and uninstalls. But didn't work, got the same result. Only solved the issue after **restarting** the computer.

Try this,

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@12.0.2
```

Then use

```
ng version
```

to see the version.

If the problem is still not solved, then **restart** the computer.

Please note that if you are installing an older CLI version to test an old application, just installing an older angular CLI will not work. It also needs a compatible Node.js installation first.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete angular version from your PC and clean npm cash.
And try to install needed version of angular.

As well as you can use ng version manager (Not recommended)

And try to delete files of angular from global npm folder

Comment: I did sir. I also uninstall node and reinstall from the start .But the condition doesn't change.